# Passing data between multiple Contexts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I've been tinkering with the React Context API for the last few days, making a small "CMS" with it as a small pet project. However I came across an interesting problem, I've been thinking a lot about it, but I might actually be overthinking it, I'd be happy to recieve any pointers as I haven't found anything like this in Google, only basic "getting started" articles.

So let's assume we have the following data models in place:

- articles
- categories
- images

I've made a Provider-Consumer pair for each of these, eg.:

```
const Context = React.createContext();

class ArticleProvider extends React.Component {
    this.state = { articles : [] };

    render() {
        <Context.Provider value={ this.state }>
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    }
}

const ArticleConsumer = (props) => (
    <Context.Consumer>
        { props.children }
    </Context.Consumer>
);
```

They are of of course a lot more fleshed out than this, but they all have this same structure.
Now the problem I have, when you edit an Article you can select a category and an image.

To solve this problem I've made component called ArticleForm. This form is a simple component, only taking props as parameter.

I also have another component called a MediaGrid this is used to display and upload images on a separate page.

So to make sure the ArticleForm can do all the things I want to I've made the following component called ArticleFormContainer, with the idea that I might be able to reuse the MediaGrid component:

```
<ArticleProvider { ...props }>
  <CategoryProvider>
    <MediaProvider>
      <ArticleConsumer>
        { (article) =>
          <CategoryConsumer>
            { (category) =>
              <MediaConsumer>
                { (media) => <ArticleForm { ...article } { ...category } { ...media } /> }
              </MediaConsumer>
            }
          </CategoryConsumer>
         }
       </ArticleConsumer>
     </MediaProvider>
   </CategoryProvider>
</ArticleProvider>
```

I can't however shake off the feeling that this is awfully busy, and might not be the best way to do it.

Any ideas how to improve this? If this isn't enough information ask and I'll post the rest of the code in a Pastebin or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts) mention the use case of requiring multiple contexts. They say

> If two or more context values are often used together, you might want to consider creating your own render prop component that provides both.

So, the basic idea is you'd be able to use your combined context throughout your app like:

```
<CombinedContextsConsumer render={({context1, context2}) => (
    <div>{context1.value}</div>
    <div>{context2.value}</div>
)}/>
```

With CombinedContextsConsumer looking something like:

```
<Context1.Consumer>
    {context1 => (
        <Context2.Consumer>
            {context2 => (
                {props.render({context1, context2})}
            )}
        </Context2.Consumer>
    )}
</Context1.Consumer>
```

You don't want the providers in this reusable component. That will cause the context data to be reset every time it's used. It will also mean that the consumers won't be sharing data between each other because they'll each have *their own copy* of the context. The providers should be higher up in the tree, at the app level if these are global contexts.

There are several packages on npm to make this job easier for you, but I've never had personal experience with them. This one looks interesting:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-compose-context-consumers

Comment: Thing is, I can't really put these any higher, there's only the <Route /> elements there, and then the react init call.

Plus that's kind of what I'm doing now I think.

Comment: Well you don't want the providers in this reusable component because then the context will get reset every time it's used. If these are global level providers they should be at the top of your app.

Comment: Yeah I know, they would get unmounted then remounted again should I navigate away, I don't really mind it in this case, but if I were to store the logged in user I would have to move them as high as possible.

Comment: @user2941726 I clarified in my answer why we don't want the providers in a reusable component. Even if in this specific case it works, it's not the correct practice. If each consumer creates its own context then why use context at all? Just use a regular component with state.

Comment: Fair point. Also saves having to copy and paste providers again and again.

Comment: @user2941726 yeah, definitely don't want to be providing again and again. Making this reusable consumer component avoids having to nest consumers, so it's a pretty nice pattern.

Comment: Too bad I could never get it to play react-router.

Comment: @user2941726 There shouldn't be a problem using react router. The providers could be high up in your app, above react-router. Anyway, if you felt my solution answered your question, it's stackoverflow etiquette to mark it as the correct answer :)